# Accuracy of PrimeQ function

Tags: number-theory, implementation-details, prime-numbers

Using `PrimeQ` in *Mathematica* 10 on integers up to $2\cdot 10^{5717}$ the function appears to work. The Documentation for *Mathematica* 5 says that `PrimeQ` is only good for integers up to $10^{16}$. Is there a definitive statement about the limit for `PrimeQ` implemented in *Mathematica* 10?

Comment: As far as I know, the test used by `PrimeQ` has been proved correct for integers up to $2^{64}$. Also, no pseudoprime (a composite number passing the test) of any size has ever been found.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123465/do-we-really-know-the-reliability-of-primeqn-for-n1016

Answer (score 14):

Turning my comment into an answer,

One of the tests performed by `PrimeQ` for machine-sized integers, namely Miller-Rabin using up to the first 12 primes as bases (as of version 10) has been proved correct for integers up to $2^{64}$ (in fact, the smallest number which that test falsely declares a prime is [known](https://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00864) to be $3186 65857 83403 11511 67461.$)

Of course,

```
PrimeQ[318665857834031151167461]

(* False *)
```

since it is rejected by a Lucas test (which is performed after a Miller-Rabin test with bases 2 and 3).

No pseudoprime (a composite number passing both tests) of any size has ever been found.

Comment: Let me ask a subsidiary question. If I tested a sequence of integers up to $2\cdot 10^{5717}$ for which `PrimeQ` reported (* False *) can I state that the next prime member of this sequence (if it exists) is greater than
 $2\cdot 10^{5717}$?

Comment: Yes, the non-determinism in these tests only applies to primality: while a `True` result may happen to be wrong (with extremely small probability and no known examples), a `False` result is a guarantee of compositeness (assuming, of course, there are no bugs in the implementation, cosmic radiation doesn't flip random bits in the computer's memory etc.)

Comment: No, it fails already on number 9 and on number 2047. The number you mentioned is much further. https://oeis.org/A006945

Comment: @ВалерийЗаподовников The number I mentioned, as explicitly stated in the answer (and in the linked paper) is the smallest strong pseudoprime to the first 12 prime bases. So when you say "it fails already on number 9 and on number 2047", I think there is some confusion as to what exactly is "it".

Comment: @ilian ok. BTW, the test uses 2020's update Baillie-PSW now, see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/283692/82985