# Is a probabilistic primality test implemented in Mathematica?

Tags: random, number-theory, prime-numbers

Imagine that I need to verify that a specific integer, like $n = 10^{1347}+3049$ is prime.

`ProvablePrimeQ` takes a lot of time, and, even if it will eventually work for this integer, it will work forever for somewhat larger integers.

`PrimeQ` works in 0.156 seconds, but, according to specification, it uses "the multiple Rabin-Miller test in bases 2 and 3 combined with a Lucas pseudoprime test". As far as I understand, its answer for every specific number is deterministic - either correct or false (no probabilities involved). It may happen that it returns false answer for $n=10^{1347}+3049$, and, in this case, it will still return false answer even if I call `PrimeQ[n]` a million times.

I do not understand why use Rabin-Miller test in bases 2 and 3 only? The theory says that if we select bases AT RANDOM, we get the correct answer with probability $3/4$. We can then repeat the test $N$ times to reduce the probability of error down to $(1/4)^N$. This way I can control the error probability.

The question is: Is there a randomised primality test implemented in Mathematica, where I can control the error probability as a parameter? Or where the error probability is given in the specification and I can reduce it by repeating the test?

Comment: Where in the documentation did you find the claim, that `PrimeQ` might return incorrect answers?

Comment: There is no randomized primality test built in as a system function. The reason to use bases 2 and 3, then go to the Lucas test, is that there is no compelling reason to believe alternatives offer any improvement. (1) A randomized set of Miller-Rabin tests would mean any incorrect outcome would be effectively unrepeatable. (2) A bunch of runs with probability 1-(1/4)^n incorrect is not really a great substitute for a faster tandem that has no known failure cases.

Comment: "As far as I understand, its answer for every specific number is deterministic - either correct or false (no probabilities involved)." That is not enough. A primality test is deterministic if it outputs True when the number is a prime and False when the input is composite with probability 1. Deterministic algorithm is ECPP and APR-CL, e.g.

Answer (score 1):

`PrimeQ` is using Miller-Rabin tests with bases 2 and 3 to ensure that n is not a square, which is a necessary test, as otherwise the choice for Q in the Lucas test will not succeed. Other similar implementations use only the Miller-Rabin test with base 2 and check if n is square afterwards. See the wiki page on Baillie-PSW primality test.

Comment: Would you please provide a source for these claims?

Comment: The wiki page on Baillie-PSW does indeed not talk about implementation. Also the Mathematica documentation does not clarify this. I have found the remark on the Mathematica implementation in Python source code I found some time ago on the web. I do not know the source at the moment (but I will dig further). I would like to know why testing with Miller-Rabin bases 2 and 3 ensures, that n is squarefree.

Comment: I just checked if any square would pass Fermat tests base 2 and 3, up to about 5*10^18. So, testing with Fermat bases 2 and 3 (or even better Miller-Rabin tests bases 2 and 3) prevents squares to pass.

Comment: @Henrik Schumacher: I posted a question on [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912834/prove-that-an-odd-square-number-cannot-be-both-a-pseudoprime-with-base-2-and-a-p) and got the answer that it is very unlikely that, if a number passes the Miller-Rabin tests with bases 2 and 3, the number is a square, but that you cannot rule it out.

Comment: Mathematica now uses 2020's Baillie–PSW, see https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.14425. No base 3 test.

Answer (score 0):

Not actually and answer to the question, but may be of interest.
Code below is a slight modification of code in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470412151) book.

```
SpspSequence[b_, n_] := With[{s = IntegerExponent[n - 1, 2]},
  NestList[Mod[#^2, n] &, PowerMod[b, (n - 1)/2^s, n], s] /. n - 1 -> -1];

StrongPseudoprimeQ[_, 1] = False;
StrongPseudoprimeQ[b_, n_] := With[{bSeq = SpspSequence[b,n]},
  Union[bSeq] == {1} || MemberQ[bSeq, -1]
]
```

StrongPseudoprimeQ above applies the Miller-Rabin test using base n. You can use that to apply Miller-Rabin to any bases you want. For example:

```
n = 1373653;
StrongPseudoprimeQ[2, n]
StrongPseudoprimeQ[3, n]
StrongPseudoprimeQ[5, n]
(*
  True
  True
  False
)*
```

Related content is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/132670/some-information-about-primeq-function), [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Baillie%5C%5BDash%5DPSW_primality_test) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/241611/primeq-versus-baillie-psw-primality-test).