# PrimeQ versus Baillie-PSW primality test

Tags: prime-numbers

I read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test#Baillie-PSW_primality_test) that Baillie-PSW primality test is proven correct up to $2^{64}$, but I understand `PrimeQ` is only proven correct up to $10^{16}$, or was that extended up to $2^{64}$? Doesn't `PrimeQ` use a variation of Baillie-PSW? For many years I have wondered why Wolfram Research hasn't verified that `PrimeQ` is correct up to $2^{64}$, and ensure it is the fastest of all known  algorithms that could make that claim.

Comment: Just curious, where have you seen that `PrimeQ` was proven correct up to $10^{16}$?

Comment: PrimeQ does use Baillie-PSW.

Answer (score 3):

The MSE post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123465/do-we-really-know-the-reliability-of-primeqn-for-n1016 may be a satisfactory affirmative answer.  It looks like the work to show `PrimeQ` is valid up to $2^{64}$ was never published, but it is still hosted here http://www.janfeitsma.nl/math/psp2/index.  Finally, a Google search found a writeup of this work that appeared in a student research forum http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-1326/ in 2015, which lends credence to the result.

Comment: The main link (used by wikipedia) is this. https://web.archive.org/web/20191121062007/http://www.trnicely.net/misc/bpsw.html